# Alert Dialog is not displaying HTML defined in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview, android-alertdialog

Please have a look at the following code

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="measurements_description"><html><font color="#FFFAF0">I want to have white color for the whole text. 
    <br/>This text comes in a new line<font color="red">This text is red </font>
    <br/>This is another line. Again, color is white </font></html></string>
```

**male_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/measurementsDescription"
            android:text="@string/measurements_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Form.java** (This is belongs to the main layout activity_form)

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int id, MenuItem item) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    TextView msg = new TextView(this);
    msg.setText("<html><u>Message</u></html>");
        
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //alertBuilder.setMessage("<html><u>Message</u></html>");
    alertBuilder.setTitle("Male Measurement Instructions");
    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.male_layout, null);
        
    alertBuilder.setView(v);
    alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
             //alertBuilder.finish();
        }
    });
        
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
        
    return true;
}
```

This is how it gets displayed, without responding to any of the HTML in the string.xml file. Why this is not changing it's colors as coded in HTML? Why it is not keeping line breaks as coded in HTML?

[image]

How to solve this issue? Please help!

Comment: You mean display `<html>` and other tags directly in dialog?

Comment: @Glenn: I mean, they are not doing what they should do. Like converting color, adding line breaks, etc.

Comment: HTML Tag `<br />` is not supported but you can use `\n`. For coloring, you can set the textview's font color like `Color.BLACK` or parse a color like `Color.parseColor("#FFFAF0")`.

Comment: You can also try `WebView`

Comment: OK, so in that case I have to edit it, inside te layout.xml file. But, there is a place in the text where the colour is getting changed to "red" only for few words. Please help

Comment: You can try `WebView`, attach it to the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

First problem is the nested `<font>`. It won't work if you have `<font>` inside an other `<font>`. You can set the `android:textColor` attribute to `#FFFFFF` and then with the `<font>` you can change the color of some text. Second you have to use `CDATA` in your string and third you have to set the text of the `TextView` from code so you can format the string with html. So you must have

**male_layout.xml**

```
...
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/measurementsDescription"

    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
...
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="measurements_description">
<![CDATA[
    I want to have white color for the whole text. 
    <br/>This text comes in a new line <font color="red">This text is red </font>
    <br/>This is another line. Again, color is white
]]>    
</string>
```

**Form.java**

```
...
String html = getString(R.string.measurements_description);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.measurementsDescription);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
...
```

Comment: I tried it. Setting it inside Form.java is not working. An error is getting generated

Comment: I implemented it before i answer, so i know that it works. Post the error so i can help you. And some code of course. Make an edit in your question

Answer (score 1):

The [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) says that only a few HTML tags (including `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>` ) are supported by the `TextView`.

If you want to show words of different colors you should use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

A complete example [here](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring).

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

Other way to do this:

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>Erste Farbe</font> <font color=#ffcc00>zweite Farbe</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HTML formatting + format string**, by declaring a string in **strings.xml**:

```
<string name="key">
    <![CDATA[
    My text and tags <b>with or without</b> variables<br/><br/>
    Answer is <u>%1$s</u>
    ]]>
</string>
```

And create your dialog:

```
String msg = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.key), "42");
Spanned htmlMsg = Html.fromHtml(msg);
builder.setMessage(htmlMsg).show();
```